# Multiple CADisplayLink's or as few as possible?

Tags: ios, cadisplaylink

Example

- I have a UIView which simply draws a custom spinner using CoreGraphics. It is updating itself using CADisplayLink so it can draw each frame.
- Another UIView subclass draws a progress-bar also using CoreGraphics. It is also updating itself using CADisplayLink.

The list could potentially go on. And as you can see codewise it is obviously easiest that each component has its own CADisplayLink.

Is it better or worse to have many CADisplayLinks? (A workaround to having multiple CADisplayLink instances would be to have one instance which sends to many delegates/blocks each callback)